# Convert std::string into varchar/varchar array for sql statement

Tags: c++, sql, stored-procedures, varchar

I am executing a proc C(.pc) file in my project, with below steps:

Step-1:
I have a string with ',' separated delimiter:

```
    string string1={"Delhi","Bombay","Pune");
```

Step-2:
I am creating a varchar

```
    varchar str[100]
```

Step-3:
copy string1 to str using strcpy/strncpy

Step-4
Executing the query

```
    select column1, column2 from table where column1 in (str.arr);
```

**The query is returning 0 values**, but if I hard code as below:

```
    select column1, column2 from table where column1 in ('Delhi','Bombay','Pune');
```

**I am getting 5 rows as output**

*****I am missing how to effictively convert the string to varchar/multiset**, which can be used in the select statemnt.***

Are there any steps for converting the string into varchar or multiset.

Comment: `std::string` is C++, not C. Do not tag C for C++ questions.